# Pandas how to select rows based on one column value and then change another column's value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a df you can have it by running this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
df = """
  contract      EndDate      option
  A00118        99999999      AC
  A00118        19831231      SLA
  A00118        99999999      TPA
  A00118        99999999      F
  A00118        99999999      FD
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(df.strip()), sep='\s+', 
                  dtype={"RB": int, "BeginDate": int, "EndDate": int,'ValIssueDate':int,'Valindex0':int})

df
```

output is:

```
contract    EndDate option
0   A00118  99999999    AC
1   A00118  19831231    SLA
2   A00118  99999999    TPA
3   A00118  99999999    F
4   A00118  99999999    FD
```

Now I want to apply a logic to each row without using .apply function ,because it is very slow.

**The logic is ,if the option equals SLA then the EndDate will be the last 4 digits of its value.**

I tried something like this:

```
df.loc[df['option']=='SLA']['EndDate']=[4:]
```

But receive syntax error

The correct output should be:

```
contract    EndDate option
0   A00118  99999999    AC
1   A00118  1231        SLA
2   A00118  99999999    TPA
3   A00118  99999999    F
4   A00118  99999999    FD
```

Comment: The error message literally tells you the solution. `df.loc[df['option']=='SLA', 'EndDate'] = 0`

Comment: @timgeb thank you so much for your response I have just edit my question ,can you help to check again.Thanks

Comment: `df.loc[df['option']=='SLA', 'EndDate'] = df['EndDate'].astype(str).str[-4:].astype(int)`

Comment: It works,can you post as an answer so that I can check it,thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.loc` with the boolean mask for the rows *and* the column name of interest. The rest is string manipulation and type casting.

```
>>> df 
  contract   EndDate option
0   A00118  99999999     AC
1   A00118  19831231    SLA
2   A00118  99999999    TPA
3   A00118  99999999      F
4   A00118  99999999     FD
>>> where = df['option'] == 'SLA', 'EndDate'
>>> df.loc[where] = df.loc[where].astype(str).str[-4:].astype(int)
>>> df 
  contract   EndDate option
0   A00118  99999999     AC
1   A00118      1231    SLA
2   A00118  99999999    TPA
3   A00118  99999999      F
4   A00118  99999999     FD
```